# Заменить несколько ссылок на пустое место

Tags: python, json

Дан json файл, в котором помимо текста есть ссылки. Как пример:  `"\"Sales Slon\"\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ALm5wu3_M5Yvj9S-L7DV9OYG6Ae5YT4Jyt7dXkI0H4NW\\u003ds120-c-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-br100\"\"0ahUKEwjl6bSxrMj6AhWIqIsKHXJUD2wQ4h4IHSgB\"\"CAESBkVnSUlCZw\\u003d\\u003d\"\"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/104389635322755437437?hl\\u003dru\"\"Рина\"\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/ACNPEu9lrZeBMO33kPXjCDJbTREa2Md_Rt6phTRtWAgz1A\\u003ds120-c-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-br100\"\"0ahUKEwjl6bSxrMj6AhWIqIsKHXJUD2wQ4h4IIygA\"\"`

Нужно заменить всё, что начинается с "https:" на пустое место, но сколько бы не искал информации, заменить именно в json файле не получилось.

Comment: а не надо менять в файле. надо считать json, произвести над ним нужные манипуляции и сохранить json в файл. только не надо рассказывать, что вы не нашли информации о том как работать с json.

Comment: если бы я нашел информацию, и смог бы её применить, то я бы не писал сюда

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите в вопрос ваш файл. Если он слишком большой, то хотя бы его часть. Но так, чтобы приведённая часть была валидной

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/JHNEB